# Music App won't airplay to HomePod mini when MacBook Pro is connected to external displays

Tags: itunes, music, big-sur, airplay, homepod

Trying to AirPlay from the Music App to my HomePod mini results in the following: "The selected movie won't play on one of your connected displays."

When I dismiss the popup and hit play it will play one song before popping up once more.
I do have two external monitors that seem to be impacting this. When disconnecting the displays AirPlay works as expected.

Is there a workaround for this?

**Full Alert:**
[image: Apple Music Popup]

Working with a MacBook Pro with M1 and two external displays connected via a DisplayLink hub.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to listen to music? Are you watching the music video perhaps? Because AFAIK HDCP is a protction mechanism to prevent you from viewing copyrighted content on seperate screens to stop you from e.g. (publicly) playing a movie on a huge projector for a big audience. What happens if you follow the advice, i.e. move the Music App to your internal MacBook screen?

Comment: Great question. The Music app is running on my MacBook internal display, and it's definitely a song and not a music video.